# android: old fragments stay on top of new fragments after transition

Tags: android, maven, android-fragments

I've come across a very peculiar bug regarding fragment transitions in android. It is always reproducible if you put your app in background during the animation of the transition. If I go from fragment B to fragment A in backwards transition, fragment B stays visible on top of fragment A. The view hierarchy doesn't show any traces of fragment B and the visible elements of fragment B are not clickable, instead the clicks get registered on the overlapped elements of fragment A underneath.

I've created a short video of the bug here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JpiU.jpg

To figure out what went wrong, I created a new application and worked myself towards the setup of my existent application. That's when I could localize the source of the bug:

`maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`

in my top-level build.gradle file. Why does it cause my app to malfunction? This seems like a huge problem to me.

Full contents of top-level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
  }
}
```

Full contents of my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mschaidinger.fragmenttransitiontest"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}


dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
  compile "com.android.support:design:26.+"
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

If I remove the repository maven.google.com from the top-level gradle file, the transition works as intended.

What did I do wrong that prevents me from using this repository without this weird side-effect?

**EDIT: added transition code**

forward transition:

```
FragmentTransaction openTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (animate != ANIM_NONE) {
  if (animate == ANIM_ENTER) {
    openTransaction = openTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
  } else {
    openTransaction = openTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit, R.anim.pop_exit, R.anim.pop_enter);
  }
}

openTransaction = openTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, fragment, String.valueOf(fragmentId));

if (addToBackStack) {
  String transactionTag = "from" + oldFragmentId + "To" + fragmentId;
  openTransaction.addToBackStack(transactionTag);
}

openTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

backward transition is simply:

```
onBackPressed();
```

**UPDATE:**

The issue isn't with the repo itself, but rather with the version of the support libraries. Locally I have only v26.0.0-alpha1 which seems to work perfectly regarding the animation problem. I tried fetching this exact version of the repository and it didn't cause any problems. I guess now I have to figure out why my code works as intended with support library v26.0.0-alpha1, but not with any newer version. I originally discovered the issue using v25.1.0, so I'm still not closer to a solution, since it's been around before the magical version v26.0.0-alpha1 and now also after that version. I figured other apps might have the same issue, but browsing through my installed apps, I couldn't find any using the same type of transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix! All my Fragments are using FragmentBase as their superclass. In FragmentBase, I keep references to the Animations created in onCreateAnimations, and I wrote a function to cancel those animations whenever I feel like it.

```
public abstract class FragmentBase extends Fragment {

    private AnimationSet animationWrapper;

    public void interruptAnimation() {
        if(animationWrapper != null) {
            animationWrapper.setDuration(0);
            animationWrapper.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AnimationSet onCreateAnimation(int transit, final boolean enter, final int nextAnim) {
        Animation anim;

        try {
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), nextAnim);
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }

        AnimationSet animationWrapper = new AnimationSet(false);
        animationWrapper.addAnimation(anim);
        this.animationWrapper = animationWrapper;
        return this.animationWrapper;
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity, I keep references to the currently visible Fragments (instances of FragmentBase) and in onPause() I call their interruptAnimation() methods.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentBase _currentFragment;
    FragmentBase _previousFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(_currentFragment != null) {
            _currentFragment.interruptAnimation();
        }
        if(_previousFragment != null) {
            _previousFragment.interruptAnimation();
        }
    }
}
```

The references to _currentFragment and _previousFragment change in a OnBackStackChangedListener I register in MainActivity.